# Do Apple help book files look for @2x images on retina screens

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, apple-help

Do Apple help books, of the `MyApp.help` format (included in the app bundle), authored for inclusion in OS X apps (from the Help menu) look for `*@2x.png` images on retina screens?

I don't see any mention of this in the Apple Help Authoring guide or the High Resolution Guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Help bundles are just collections of HTML pages that are displayed in a web view — so you can use `@2x` images just like you do on web pages. (Plus, I just tried and [you can clearly see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYp5K.png) that retina content works!) For more details, see [this page](https://developer.apple.com/resources/high-resolution/) on Apple's developer site.

Comment: Thank you! On a related side note, I was going to dig through the help file in the PhotoBooth.app bundle to figure this out, but couldn't find it. Are the help files for the stock Apple apps not stored in the bundles?

Comment: I see it in my copy: `Photo Booth.app/Contents/Resources/PhotoBooth.help`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. That's what I get for programming with a fever. I spent 15 minutes looking for it last night. Thanks.